# DataMapper enum field doesn't persist when saved or updated

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, ruby-datamapper, enumerated-types

I am trying to map a legacy MySQL database with a fresh DataMapper model.

MySQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `backer` (
  `backer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `secret` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('pending','ready') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',  # relevant bit
  PRIMARY KEY (`backer_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `backer_id` (`secret`),
  KEY `email` (`email`,`status`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8166 ;
```

DataMapper model:

```
class Backer
  include DataMapper::Resource
  storage_names[:default] = "backer"     

  property :id,      Serial, :field => "backer_id"
  property :secret,  String, :field => "secret"
  property :email,   String, :field => "email"
  property :status,  Enum[ :pending, :ready ], :field => "status", :default => "pending"
  has n, :items, :child_key => "backer_id"
end

DataMapper.finalize
```

With most attributes, I can persist:

```
b = Backer.first
b.first_name = "Daniel"
b.save!
# Backer.first.first_name == "Daniel"
```

It persists fine. 
But when I do it with an `enum`:

```
b = Backer.first
b.status = :pending
b.save!

# b.status == :pending
# Backer.first.status != :pending
# Backer.first.update!(:status => :pending) ...
```

Updates/saves to an `enum` field doesn't seem to persist it.

SQL looks typically like:

```
1.9.3p327 :019 > Backer.last.update(:status => :ready)
 ~ (0.000349) SELECT `backer_id`, `secret`, `email`, `status` FROM `backer` ORDER BY `backer_id` DESC LIMIT 1
 ~ (0.000190) UPDATE `backer` SET `status` = 2 WHERE `backer_id` = 8166
 => true
```

But when I view the object (e.g. `Backer.last`) then `status` is not changed.

**UPDATE**

I've verified that the enumerated `status` field in the MySQL database is being persisted. However, the enumerated `status` property in the DataMapper class doesn't reflect this at all (is always `nil`).

What's happening here?

Comment: Does `b.reload`ing help?

Comment: Ah, no wait, DataMapper `Enum` is persisted as `Integer`, whereas MySQL `enum` is a string. So you'd most probably need to patch `DataMapper::Property::Enum` to support MySQL `enum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @morbusg: that's one solution.

The other one was to change the `Enum` at my end to a `String` and that's worked fine for my purposes.